# Ansible: how to specify ipv6.method in nmcli module?

Tags: ansible, ipv6, nmcli

In order to set up a manual ipv6 address in RHEL7 using nmcli, one would do:

```
nmcli con modify eth1 ipv6.method manual ipv6.addresses "abba::cafe/64"
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the same with ansible's `nmcli` module.
I have the following task:

```
- name: "setup ipv6 address (eth1)"
  nmcli:
    conn_name: "eth1"
    type: ethernet
    ip6: "{{ networking_ipv6_eth1_addr }}"
    gw6: "{{ networking_ipv6_eth1_gw }}"
    state: present
```

The problem is there's no `method` parameter, which in some cases results in an error when the `ipv6.method` value is incompatible with setting a manual IPv6 address:

```
Error: Failed to modify connection 'eth1': ipv6.addresses: this property is not allowed for 'method=ignore
```

I could probably fix this by setting `ipv6.method` to `auto` in a shell task before this one (it doesn't throw the error), and to `manual` after, but that is an awful solution.

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Right, it seems in RHEL7 even `nmtui` do not have the option `ignore`, but RHEL8 has.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter exists it's called `method6`

See [HERE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#parameter-method6)

Answer (score -1):

```
nmcli con modify eth1 ipv6.addresses "" ipv6.gateway "" ipv6.method disabled
```